# Why does Internet Explorer not process the same code in a consistent manner?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-platform

I am currently developing web applications for a legacy environment with a mixed blend of browser access. While the bulk of clients who will be using the sites being developed are able to use Chrome and Firefox, there exists a segment that are constrained to the use of Internet Explorer (a modified version of IE11). This is also a multi-network learning environment (users will access the sites on two distinct wide area networks and their own Internet computers), with WAN network having its own limitations of what can be downloaded, and restrictions as to how scripting is employed. It has been... interesting adapting to these requirements.

The key has been to keep things simple. Caveman levels of simple. HTML, Javascript, and CSS only. No no APIs, no JQuery. Just code as plain as possible, developed for IE with a hope that it still works the same elsewhere. Until this point I have managed to cobble together some small miracles (given my rusty skills) including a few different image galleries, minor on site animation, and all but the progress bar on a common look/feel  audio player. I am now faced with the most ridiculous of stalling points: in-line modal style display.

The client in this case wants a small dialogue to open up when a user clicks on a mapped area of a window:

[image: This is what it will look like.]

The MODAL element is not working, so I have bodged together a quick paragraph over a rectangle, with an X in another paragraph placed to close it (caveman writing petroglyphs here). Everything to be displayed is stored in a DIV named `pop,` which defaults to hidden in the style sheet. When a user clicks on the mapped area of an image on the screen it is set to unhide:

```
<img id="popIt" src="assets/001_01_IM_04B.jpg" alt="" width="537" height="345" usemap="#TDLTable">
<map name="TDLTable">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0,289,537,345" href="#" onClick="showIt()">
</map>
```

The function showIt() is as simple as:

```
pop.style.visibility = "visible";
pop.style.display = "block";
```

In order to close the dialogue, an event is fired when the X paragraph is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("popOff").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("popUp").style.visibility = "hidden";
document.getElementById("popUp").style.display = "none";
```

The variance between code is the result of attempted work-arounds, and to prove both methods work outside of IE. All of this, bodged together as it might be, works in Chrome and Firefox on the networks I am constrained to using, but does not do a thing in Internt Explorer. The thing that stymies me is that the existing code I am working with contains a similar implimentation to switch between languages. It uses the format:

```
function toggleLang() {
 if(document.getElementById("toggleEnglish").style.visibility == "visible" ) {
  document.getElementById("toggleEnglish").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("toggleEnglish").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toggleFrench").style.visibility = "visible"; 
  document.getElementById("toggleFrench").style.display = "block"; }
 else {
  document.getElementById("toggleFrench").style.visibility = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("toggleFrench").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("toggleEnglish").style.visibility = "visible"; 
  document.getElementById("toggleEnglish").style.display = "block"; }
}
```

Given that the code above works, and I am using the same call-outs for my own code, is there something I am missing? Why do the visibility and display changes work in IE for one application, but not another on the same page?

Comment: have you checked if users are in IE's compatibility mode?  I use the meta tag to force IE-edge (latest available version) for every project I do now.

Comment: Unfortunately the security constraints on the network limit what users can change in settings, and compatibility mode is not an option.